# ¿Cómo dar formato de celdas al importar txt a Excel?

Tags: excel, vb6, vba

¿Podrían indicarme por favor un formato de celda texto a todas las celdas de las hojas que voy importando de .txt a [excel](/questions/tagged/excel)?

Porque por ejemplo tengo datos que comienzan con ceros, y como están en formato de números, u horas o fechas no me importan con los ceros iniciales, por ejemplo si tengo la hora `06:30` en el txt, luego en el excel me aparecerá `6:30`.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub ImportarTxt_Click()
Dim Origen
On Error Resume Next
Origen = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Escritorio\"
milibro = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set navegador = CreateObject("shell.application")
Carpeta = navegador.browseforfolder(0, "SELECCIONA CARPETA", 0, Origen).items.Item.Path
ChDir Carpeta & "\"
archi = Dir("*.txt")
Do While archi <> ""
    Dim nom() As String
    ReDim nom(Len(archi) - 1)
        For i = 1 To Len(archi)
             nom(i - 1) = Mid$(archi, i, 1)
        Next
            nombre = nom(0) + "" + nom(1)
    If nombre <> "CT" And nombre <> "AF" And nombre <> "AD" And nombre <> "US" And nombre <> "AN" Then
    Workbooks.OpenText archi, origin:=xlWindows, startrow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True, Local:=False
    Dim celda As Range
    For Each celda In ActiveSheet
    celda.Value = CStr(celda)
    MsgBox ("Pse por aqui")
    Next celda
    otro = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveSheet.Copy before:=Workbooks(milibro).Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 20

    Workbooks(otro).Close False
    End If
    archi = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Has investigado al respecto? Yo uso [NumberFormat en C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-format-excel.htm), pero desconozco que exista uno equivalente en vba. Con esto puedes investigar y si encuentras la respuesta, puedes publicarla y aceptarla. Saludos.

Comment: Claramente he investiago bastante, Estoy hace rato en las mismas intentando diferentes soluciones pero no me funciona ninguna

Comment: Andrés, añade a tu pregunta los enlaces de tu investigación.

Comment: Si te digo la verdad, yo me meto a páginas y si no me sirven pues me salgo jejeje, pero creo que encontré la solución, es simplemente lo que tu dijiste. ActiveWorksheet.Range("Rango).NumberFormat = "hh:mm" dentro de un cíclo. Muchas gracias David!

Comment: Andrés, publica tu respuesta y acéptala para que no siga apareciendo como una pregunta sin respuesta.